# Why is function object faster than function in C++?

Tags: c++, optimization, lambda, compiler-optimization

I read C++ coding standards (Herb Sutter and Andrei Alexandrescu) and two articles below.

Intuitively, a function object has additional overhead compared to a function, because it is an object in C++. However, it seems that function object invocation usually outperforms function calling. I know that inlining is one of the optimizations function object provides.

So my questions are:

1. Why are function objects so fast? Is it all because of inlining?
2. How does the function object get implemented? Is it translated into ordinary function call at compile time? Or are there any difference in runtime logic?
3. Are there any cases in which function objects are slower than functions?

[Detailed difference between functor's call and function call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3938321/detailed-difference-between-functors-call-and-function-call)

[When do you use function objects in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2351437/when-do-you-use-function-objects-in-c)

Comment: Its basically all in the inlining and other optimalization it enables.

Comment: *"Intuitively, a function object has additional overhead compared to a function, because it is an object in C++"* I don't understand this reasoning. Why should an object be slow?

Comment: ***One* question per question, please.**

Comment: Of course, the comparison is with a function *pointer*, not a function. Calling a function indirectly (i.e. via a pointer) can't usually be inlined, and may well be slower than a direct call to a function object's member function even if neither is inlined.

Comment: C++ object does not create any additional overhead
On the low-level class method is just a function with additional hidden parameter (this), unless it's virtual, of course

Comment: Thanks for linking to the useful article. So seems the answer is that it would all translated in compile time. I thought there are overhead for calling function object. And I finally got what the inlining actually means. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13722426/why-can-lambdas-be-better-optimized-by-the-compiler-than-plain-functions