# C - How to declare an object type of arbitrary byte size?

Tags: c, object, types, size

I want to loop over arrays in a type-independent manner by casting a void pointer to an array of objects of arbitrary byte size. I know the size of the array and the size of its items, but not the type of the items. Is there a safe and portable way of doing this?

All I can think of at the moment is to create a struct with one member, a char array of the required size. But I'm not sure how safe and portable this is as a solution, due to possibility of alignment issues and possibly other problems I haven't thought of.

Example code of what I want to do:

```
void myFunc(void * arrV, int len, size_t arrSize, size_t itemSize) {
  // type definition, for array item of size itemSize
  struct xxxx {char[itemSize];};
  struct xxxx * arr = (struct xxxx *) arrV;
  for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    if (i == 100) {
      struct xxxx arrItem = arr[i];
      // do something with arrItem;
    }
  }
}
```

Edit: question title edited as it was phrased incorrectly.

Comment: What is the actual problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Functions such as `qsort()` and `bsearch()` use `void *base` to point to the start of the array, `size_t count` to specify how many elements are in the array and `size_t size` to specify the size of each element (e.g. `void qsort(void *base, size_t count, size_t size, int (*compar)(const void *, const void *));`).  You have `len`, `arrSize`, and `itemSize` — three sizes.  What's what?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The params are there to show I know array length, byte size and its item byte size. I don't know type of array items. Nevertheless, I want to loop over items of the array, by declaring a one-use object of required byte size. How to declare such an object?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The aforementioned functions also take the `compar` function which is specifically designed for the the type in the array. That `// do something with arrItem;` part in the OP code should be implemented similarly. Not much can be done with this array otherwise.

Comment: @EugeneSh. The problem I want to solve is as stated: how to create object type of arbitrary size in C, safely and portably. Say I want an object of 32 bytes. How to declare it? One use case is as stated, looping over an array of unknown type, but known count of items, array byte size, byte size of its items. I hope that's all clear enought.

Comment: This is not a problem, this is a proposed solution to some more concrete problem, which might have better solutions. See [XY-problem](https://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: If creating object types of arbitrary size is not a problem then I give up on StackOverflow!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to loop over arrays in a type-independent manner by casting a void pointer to an array of objects of arbitrary byte size. I know the size of the array and the size of its items, but not the type of the items. Is there a safe and portable way of doing this?

It depends on how portable you need it to be.  Your suggestion of an defining a structure type containing an array of the desired length is not viable for two reasons:

1. In standard C, structure types may not be defined as containing variable-length arrays, and
2. There is no portable way to ensure that the structure type would not contain padding (which would make its size wrong).

Additionally, the variable-length array feature is optional in C11 and C17 (though it is a mandatory in C99, and some form of it might return to mandatory status in C2X).  But if you are willing to rely on VLAs then you can use them more directly for your purpose:

```
void myFunc(void *arrV, int len, size_t arrSize, size_t itemSize) {
    char (*items)[itemSize] = arrV;  // pointer to (variable-length) array

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        // ... do something with items[i] ...
    }
}
```

If you don't want to depend on VLAs then the conventional way that functions such as `qsort()` do it is to convert the `void *` to a `char *` and perform appropriate arithmetic with that:

```
void myFunc(void *arrV, int len, size_t arrSize, size_t itemSize) {
    char *items = arrV;

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        char *item_start = items + (i * itemSize);
        // ... do something with *item_start
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I was hoping to be able to use the arbitrarily sized object type to also assign array items, but neither solution permits this. Is there no way in C of accomplishing that?

Comment: @Theod'Or, if you mean to assign via the assignment operator (`=`) then no, there is no portable way.  Instead, use `memcpy()`.  Or `memmove()` if there is a possibility that the source and destination overlap.

Comment: I see in the `memcpy` code that it will try to optimize for speed by casting the array to `long` for copying by word rather than byte. That's pretty much what I'm after except I would prefer to not be constrained to `long` size. Oh well, `memcpy` will have to do. Thanks again.

Comment: @Theod'Or, yes, you can assume that `memcpy()` is highly optimized.  You may even find that the compiler optimizes it out completely in some cases.  But you cannot look at ***the*** code for `memcpy()` in any global sense.  There is no one true implementation.  I presume that what you looked at is the code for the `memcpy()` of some particular version of some particular C standard library implementation that is of interest to you.

Answer (score 2):

Use malloc to allocate memory

```
void * itemArr = malloc(arrSize * itemSize);
```

`malloc` dynamically allocates memory equal to the size of its first parameter (in bytes).

Once you are done with using it, you can `free` that memory to make it usable again.

`free(itemArr);`

Edit: Ok here is trial 2

I do not think this:

```
struct xxxx {char[itemSize];};
```

is valid syntax in C, you need to have an identifier.

Also my argument still stands, if you want to create an object from an unknown type of arbitrary size, you can use `malloc` instead of a normal array. Use malloc, cast it to a void* or char*, and treat it as an unknown data type. A struct, or for that matter data types, are all abstractions. You can treat any piece of memory as a non-standard data type. Also as far as I know `malloc` shouldn't cause alignment issues as malloc pointers are always aligned

Comment: Pretty sure the OP is well aware of this. The actual question is about "But I'm not sure how safe and portable this is as a solution, due to possibility of alignment issues and possibly other problems I haven't thought of"

Comment: @EugeneSh. I am not sure OP is aware of malloc. The post doesn't mention malloc at all. Either way it should be ok I guess.

Comment: Downvoted for not addressing the question.

Comment: @Theod'Or it is addressing the question tho.  " I know the size of the array and the size of its items, but not the type of the items. Is there a safe and portable way of doing this?", I think malloc is such a way

Comment: @Theod'Or You'd better clarify the question

Comment: My question is not about allocating memory for the array!

Comment: @Theod'Or oh, I think I understand your question better now. One more question, what is the ```arrSize``` parameter for, is it unused?

Comment: @Theod'Or added an edit

Comment: Thank you - downvote removed as it was my fault, the question title was phrased incorrectly, now edited.

Answer (score 2):

The size of a structure has to be known at compile time.  You can have a flexible array member ([FAM](http://port70.net/%7E%E2%80%A6/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2.1p3) and [more FAM](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2.1p18)) in a structure, but that doesn't help, not least because the size of the structure doesn't include the size of the FAM.  Your attempt to create a type `struct xxxx` with a size determined at run time is doomed.

The C standard has two functions that process arrays of arbitrary type and size: `bsearch()` and `qsort()`.  They use `void *base` to point to the start of the array, `size_t count` to specify how many elements are in the array and `size_t size` to specify the size of each element:

```
void qsort(void *base, size_t count, size_t size,
           int (*compar)(const void *, const void *));
```

These functions both take a pointer to a function that compares two values in the array by whatever mechanism the function chooses.

To achieve your goal, you will need to emulate them.  You've not specified how you expect to process the values in the array, and that would give you headaches unless you adopt a similar technique where you pass a pointer to each element of the array to a function.

You can process an array of arbitrary type and size with ordinary pointer arithmetic.  Despite what the GCC compiler permits, Standard C says you can't do arithmetic on `void *` values, but you can do arithmetic on `char *` values.  As long as the size of the items is the result of `sizeof(TheActualType)`, you can step through data that is appropriately aligned.  I'm assuming that in your interface, `arrSize == len * itemSize` (see also my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74046156/c-how-to-create-an-object-of-arbitrary-byte-size#comment130740680_74046156)), though that's barely critical as I redesign the interface to your function to more closely match the standard functions.  I add a callback function which is given a `void *` argument that can be safely cast to whatever type is being processed:

```
void ProcessArray(void *base, size_t count, size_t size, void (*processor)(void *))
{
    char *array = base;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        (*processor)(array + i * itemSize);
    }
}
```

The function pointer should be of the type shown.  Many people take the shortcut of defining a processing function such as `void ProcessingFunction(SomeType *arg);` and passing that to a function.  That includes such prestigious references as Brian W Kernighan and Dennis M Ritchie
[The C Programming Language, 2nd Edn](https://smile.amazon.com/dp/0131103628) (1988).  But the C standard says (in [§6.3.2.3 (Conversions of) Pointers](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.3p8)) that calling a pointer to a function with the wrong type is undefined behaviour.  So, strictly, you should not pass such a function to a function like `ProcessArray()`.  You need a function like:

```
void ProcessingFunction(void *arg)
{
    SomeType *ptr = arg;    /* Cast not necessary in C */
    …process data using ptr->member…
}
```

If need be, you can pass a 'context' pointer to the functions to convey information other than the element being processed to the processing function:

```
void ProcessArrayWithContext(void *base, size_t count, size_t size, void (*processor)(void *arg, void *context), void *context)
{
    char *base = arrV;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        (*processor)(base + i * itemSize, context);
    }
}
```

And then:

```
void ProcessingFunctionWithContext(void *arg, void *context)
{
    SomeType *ptr = arg;    /* Cast not necessary in C */
    ContextInfo *ctxt = context;
    …process data using ptr->member and ctxt->info…
}
```

There is precedent for this with the non-standard `qsort_r()` functions defined by Linux and BSD (macOS).  However, be aware that the BSD and Linux interfaces to `qsort_r()` are different.  The Linux version looks like:

```
void qsort_r(void *base, size_t nmemb, size_t size,
             int (*compar)(const void *, const void *, void *),
             void *arg);
```

The comparator takes the context as the third, non-const argument, and `qsort_r()` passes `arg` as that third argument.  The BSD version looks like:

```
void qsort_r(void *base, size_t nel, size_t width, void *thunk,
             int (*compar)(void *, const void *, const void *));
```

The comparator takes the context as the first, non-const argument, and the context is passed before the pointer to the comparator.

In the Linux code, the function effectively contains:

```
void *v1 = …;
void *v2 = …;
int rc;
if ((rc = (*compar)(v1, v2, arg)) < 0)
    …
else if (rc > 0)
    …
else
    …
```

The BSD effectively contains:

```
void *v1 = …;
void *v2 = …;
int rc;
if ((rc = (*compar)(arg, v1, v2)) < 0)
    …
else if (rc > 0)
    …
else
    …
```

See also [Pass extra parameter to comparator for `qsort()`?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46042467/15168).

Obviously, the callback (processing) function could be given other types.  For example, you might have it return a value of type `int` and the loop could exit early if the value returned is not `0`, or if it is `0`.  The options are legion.

Comment: Thank you! Please see my comment to John Bollinger's answer.

Comment: You can't do array assignments in C using the assignment operator.  You have to use `memmove()` or `memcpy()`.  (You can initialize arrays; you can copy structures containing arrays — but the size of those arrays is known at compile time.). You've not yet been clear about what you plan to do with the data that you don't know the type of — it isn't at all obvious how you're going to process the values.  I've covered some legitimate (and portable) ways of doing it, but you've not been forthcoming on the effort.

Comment: I'm primarily after generic knowledge, not wanting to be pinned down by any particular use case too much. What I got from this QnA is that what I'm after is not possible, and for arbitrary-length assignments I should use `memcpy`. See my second comment to JB. Thanks again for your help.