# C++ STL sort() function, binary predicate

Tags: c++, sorting, stl

I have a piece of code that confuses me:

```
   sort(data, data+count, greater<int>() );
```

it is a sort function in the C standard library. I am having trouble figuring out the meaning of the third argument. I have read that it is called a binary predicate. What does that mean and how can I make my own such predicate?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The third argument is called a [predicate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predicate_%28mathematical_logic%29). You can think of a predicate as *a function that takes a number of arguments and returns `true` or `false`*.

So for example, here is a predicate that tells you whether an integer is odd:

```
bool isOdd(int n) {
    return n & 1;
}
```

The function above takes one argument, so you could call it a *[unary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unary_operation)* predicate. If it took two arguments instead, you would call it a *[binary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_operation)* predicate. Here is a binary predicate that tells you if its first argument is greater than the second:

```
bool isFirstGreater(int x, int y) {
    return x > y;
}
```

Predicates are commonly used by very general-use functions to allow the caller of the function to specify how the function should behave by writing their own code (when used in this manner, a predicate is a specialized form of *[callback](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_%28computer_programming%29)*). For example, consider the `sort` function when it has to sort a list of integers. What if we wanted it to sort all odd numbers before all even ones? We don't want to be forced to write a new sort function each time that we want to change the sort order, because the mechanics (the algorithm) of the sort is clearly not related to the specifics (in what order we want it to sort).

So let's give `sort` a predicate of our own to make it sort in reverse:

```
// As per the documentation of sort, this needs to return true
// if x "goes before" y. So it ends up sorting in reverse.
bool isLarger(int x, int y) {
    return x > y;
}
```

Now this would sort in reverse order:

```
sort(data, data+count, isLarger);
```

The way this works is that `sort` internally compares pairs of integers to decide which one should go before the other. For such a pair `x` and `y`, it does this by calling `isLarger(x, y)`.

So at this point you know what a predicate is, where you might use it, and how to create your own. But what does `greater<int>` mean?

[`greater<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y85yzaz5%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) is a binary predicate that tells if its first argument is greater than the second. It is also a *templated `struct`*, which means it has many different forms based on the type of its arguments. This type needs to be specified, so `greater<int>` is the *template specialization* for type `int` (read more on C++ templates if you feel the need).

So if `greater<T>` is a `struct`, how can it also be a predicate? Didn't we say that predicates are *functions*?

Well, `greater<T>` is a function in the sense that it is *callable*: it defines the operator `bool operator()(const T& x, const T& y) const;`, which makes writing this legal:

```
std::greater<int> predicate;
bool isGreater = predicate(1, 2); // isGreater == false
```

Objects of class type (or `struct`s, which is pretty much the same in C++) which are callable are called *[function objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_object)* or *functors*.

Comment: I suspect the large example would still sort in ascending order. `greater` makes it sort in descending order.

Comment: but in `sort(data, data+count, isSmaller);` you never mention `x` or `y` how does `isSmaller` know what to compare?

Comment: @Niello: Added a small explanation after the `sort` call. Is it sufficient?

Comment: ah, so x and y basically represent elements of array to be sorted? right? and when the sorting process is being done it checks the order of elements?

Comment: @Niello: Yes, that's right. Deciding which pairs of elements to compare, when to compare them, and what to do with the comparison result is all part of the sort algorithm (so you can't affect that). But using the callback (or predicate if you prefer) you can decide what the comparison result will be.

Answer (score 7):

There is a class template called `greater` which needs a type argument. So you provide `int` as one. It became `greater<int>` and you create an instance of this class and pass it to the function as third argument.

Such an object is called [function object or simply functor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_object#In_C_and_C.2B.2B) in C++, as the class overloads `()` operator. It's a callable entity. Its like this:

```
template<typename T>
struct greater
{
   bool operator()(const T &a, const T &b)
   {
      //compare a and b and return either true or false.
      return a > b;
   }
};
```

If you create an instance of `greater<int>` and, say, the object is `g`, then you can write `g(100,200)` which evaluates to a boolean value, as the expression `g(100,200)` calls `operator()`, passing `100` as first argument and `200` as second argument, and `operator()` compares them and return either `true` or `false`.

```
       std::cout << g(100,200) << std::endl;
       std::cout << g(200,100) << std::endl;
```

Output:

```
0
1
```

Online demo : http://ideone.com/1HKfC

Answer (score 3):

A binary predicate is any function/object that receives two objects (hence binary) and returns a `bool` (hence [predicate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predicate_%28mathematical_logic%29)); the idea is that it evaluates if the two objects satisfy some particular condition - in the example, if one is greater than the other.

You can create a predicate either by just defining a function with the correct signature

```
bool IsIntGreater(int First, int Second)
{
    return First>Second;
}
```

and passing the name of the function as the argument (this will result in passing a function pointer), or creating a function object (a *functor*), i.e. an object which overloads the function call operator and thus can be used as a function; the `std::greater<T>` type is a template functor, and in your snippet a temporary object of type `std::greater<int>` is created and passed to the `std::sort` algorithm.

Functors have several advantages over functions, especially when they have to be passed as arguments, have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2351437/when-do-you-use-function-objects-in-c/2351485#2351485) for more information about this.

Answer (score 1):

See `comp` in http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/

It is the function that does the comparison.