# How does sorting in descending order works in c++?

Tags: c++, sorting

I was searching how to sort a vector in a descending order then I found this code

```
std::sort(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), std::greater<int>());
```

It works but I just want to know how it works

Comment: if you don't specify `std::greater<int>()` for the third argument, what does it do instead?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ STL sort() function, binary predicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372132/c-stl-sort-function-binary-predicate)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The third argument to `std::sort` is a functor/function that returns `true` if the first argument is to be placed before the second element in the sort order.

`std::greater<int>::operator()(...)` returns `true` if the first argument is greater than the second argument.

Consequently, use of `std::greater<int>()` as the third argument to `std::sort` results in the collection of objects to be sorted in descending order.

Answer (score 2):

The `std::sort` function expects you<sup>†</sup> to give it a function that tells it how to sort a range in ascending order, so by default it'll use something like `std::less<int>()`.

By providing a function with the opposite effect (i.e. `std::greater<int>()`) you are turning that expectation literally on its head, resulting in a completely legal "mirror-image" of the default behaviour. That is, a reverse sort.

A different way of explaining it is that, at each step of its algorithm, when it wants to know whether one element *A* should go "before" another element *B*, it will ask `std::greater<int>()`, which will tell it: yes, one element *A* should go "before" another element *B* if `A > B`, and there you go.

```
 5   3   2   1
   >   >   >
```

This is contrary to the default behaviour which uses something like `<` instead:

```
 1   2   3   5
   <   <   <
```

<sub><sup>†</sup> *Of course, you can actually give it a function that defines any other order you like (subject to certain constraints), so there are plenty more options. Here I explore only the two most obvious sorting methodologies.*</sub>

Comment: Sadly the opposite of `std::greater` is `std::less` and not, for some reason, `std::lesser`.

Comment: Admittedly I've done a poor job of dumbing this down. I wanted to start from the OP's assumptions and segue into facts but.. meh ^_^

Comment: I like the ascii art though!

Comment: @Useless: Yeah that was the fun part ^_^

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for `std::sort` ([here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) amongst other places) says things like

> Sorts the elements in the range [first, last) in ascending order.

This is a convenient simplification, but it's confusing when you don't *want* ascending order.

It's more useful to think that `sort` rearranges your range according so some function - let's call it `pre` - which says for any pair of elements, which one should come before (precede) the other.

That is, the function looks something like

```
bool pre(int a, int b); // return true if a should precede b
```

The *default* behaviour, if you don't specify something else, is to use `std::less`, which will do roughly this:

```
bool less(int a, int b) { return a<b; }
```

and this default (where the smaller value always precedes the larger) gives you a result sorted in ascending order.

If you specify `std::greater`, you're saying the *larger* value should always precede the *smaller* (because if `greater(a,b)==true`, that means both that `a>b` and also that `a` will precede `b` in the output).

So, this is the same as saying the result is sorted in descending order.

---

NB. I called the comparison `pre` both because it tells you which elements should precede which, and also because it is a [*predicate*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Predicate) (specifically a [BinaryPredicate](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/BinaryPredicate) and even more specifically a [Comparison](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Compare)).

Comment: Yeah that's better

Comment: It's surprisingly hard to write clearly about, it feels like it wants to turn into a textbook chapter. We'll see how many people agree that my precedes/predicate thing is actually useful :)