# Not sure about my interpretation of function declaration in C++?

Tags: c++, constants

It seems to be stupid question but I have never seen something like this!

```
int operator() (const std::string& s1, const std::string& s2) const
```

to me operator is a const member function that return an intger and no variable argument!
but need two const variables  s1 and s2?!?! I can't get the point of this!

```
class str_dist_ : 
public std::binary_function<std::string, std::string, int> {
public:
  int op() (const std::string& s1, const std::string& s2) const
  {
    if (s1 == s2)
      return 0;
    else if (s1.empty())
      return std::max(s2.size()/2, 1u);
    else if (s2.empty())
      return std::max(s1.size()/2, 1u);
    else 
      return min_edit_distance(s1, s2, zero_one_cost<char>(' '));
  }
  std::string empty() const { return std::string(); }
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `operator()` part says that objects of type `str_dist_` can be "called", as though it were a function. The `(const std::string& s1, const std::string& s2)` tells us what the argument actually are.

For example, say we have an object `str_dist_ obj;`, and two `std::string` objects, `str1` and `str2`. Then we can write something like this

```
int result = obj(str1, str2);
```

Under the covers, the previous line is identical to

```
int result = obj.operator()(str1, str2);
```

Notice that the first set of parenthesis are part of the name of the member function `operator()`, while the second set actually lists the arguments.

If you want more information, look up Functors or Function Objects. These are the terms used to refer to things such as `str_dist_` objects, which have the `operator()` defined for them. If you google either of those terms, you're sure to find a lot of information.

Answer (score 2):

It's the parenthesis-operator (or "function-call operator"):

```
Foo x;
int n = x(12, 'a');
int m = x.operator()(12, 'a'); // equivalent
```

Here the operator was declared as `int Foo::operator()(int, char)`.

Answer (score 2):

It's the "function call operator", it allows an object to be used "as a function", i.e.:

```
str_dist_ myObject;
cout<<myObject("A string", "Another string"); // calls operator()
```

The first two parentheses denote that it's the function call operator (as the `+` would denote that it's the `+` operator, etc.), then follows the arguments list.

The whole point of overloading the function call operator is to create [functors (function objects)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_object), that [have several advantages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2351437/when-do-you-use-function-objects-in-c/2351485#2351485) over plain functions.